# How to debug yt-dlp

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, youtube-dl

I would like to understand how yt-dlp (or yt-downloader) is able to download my mixcloud mix.

If I run `python .\__main__.py https://www.mixcloud.com/DJJazzyJeff/magnificent-live-mix-tapes-20210520-234619/`

the script is downloading the mix. If first started pdb by:

`python -m pdb .\__main__.py https://www.mixcloud.com/DJJazzyJeff/magnificent-live-mix-tapes-20210520-234619/`

The script was not able to find the **yt_dlp module**

Using `pip3 install yt_dlp` fixed this issue. So now I can use *n* or *next* but I don't see how the script fetches the json string. Using *step* instead provides so many (useless) information that it also not helps.

Next thing I tried is directly before and after the script download the mix in debugging mode to use the pdb command *ll*, but this doesn't help either.

```
-> yt_dlp.main()
(Pdb) ll
  1     #!/usr/bin/env python3
  2     from __future__ import unicode_literals
  3
  4     # Execute with
  5     # $ python yt_dlp/__main__.py (2.6+)
  6     # $ python -m yt_dlp          (2.7+)
  7
  8     import sys
  9
 10     if __package__ is None and not hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
 11         # direct call of __main__.py
 12         import os.path
 13         path = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))
 14         sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(path)))
 15
 16     import yt_dlp
 17
 18     if __name__ == '__main__':
 19  ->     yt_dlp.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things yt-dlp does before and after the actual extraction. So setting breakpoints from the very start will be tedious

First run yt-dlp normally and identify what extractor is responsible for the download. In this case, you can see the extractor name is `mixcloud`.

```
➤ yt-dlp https://www.mixcloud.com/DJJazzyJeff/magnificent-live-mix-tapes-20210520-234619
[mixcloud] DJJazzyJeff_magnificent-live-mix-tapes-20210520-234619: Downloading JSON metadata
[mixcloud] DJJazzyJeff_magnificent-live-mix-tapes-20210520-234619: Downloading m3u8 information
[mixcloud] DJJazzyJeff_magnificent-live-mix-tapes-20210520-234619: Downloading MPD manifest

ERROR: Interrupted by user
```

Now search the codebase for an extractor with that `IE_NAME`. In case the name is not explicitly defined anywhere, look for the class that has the same name, but ending with `IE`. You'll see that the extractor in this case is [MixcloudIE](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/d8cf8d97a8dbc9602556de474af133b5ab0e0a29/yt_dlp/extractor/mixcloud.py#L35)

The code responsible for the extraction is in the `_real_extract` and `_real_initialize` (if defined) functions of this class. From here you try to read or use `pdb` to follow the code